# XCode 5: Is there any way to group/filter/sort what shows up in code-completion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, code-completion

For a very simple object like this:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property(strong) NSObject* thingAboutMyObject;
- (void) aThingToDo;
- (void) moreToDo;
- (void) yetAnotherAction;
@end
```

Someone working with MyObject gets code completion which includes all of the methods and properties from NSObject.  It makes sense why this happens, but for a majority of cases, the methods I care most about are in the class itself.  I'd like to know if there is a way, when creating a class, to hint to the xcode IDE that you want to 'highlight' the actual interface when working with objects of the class.

I've seen a few classes which seem to 'handle' this by duplicating the class name in the method definitions, so that they sort together in the completion list, like:

```
- (void) myobjectAThingToDo;
- (void) myobjectMoreToDo;
- (void) myobjectYetAnotherAction;
```

But that doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution (`[myObject myobjectAThingToDo]`) AND it breaks down horribly in situations where polymorphism is involved.

---

Here's an example of what an 'ideal' solution would be.  I might actually make a formal feature request of it, if someone doesn't provide a suitable alternative.  But for now, it should at least clarify what I'm asking for.

It would be great if there was a way to hint to code completion that my completion list should be grouped by class, like:

**MyObject**

- [M] aThingToDo
- [M] moreToDo
- [M] thingAboutMyClass
- [M] yetAnotherAction

**NSObject**

- [M] accessibilityActivate
- [M] accessibilityActivation
- ...

Presumably, a deeper object hierarchy could just list parent classes in the same style, ordering by inheritance 'proximity.'  A list like this could easily still filter as you type and eliminate class groupings which have no matches.

---

**Can anyone suggest solutions to help with this?**  I doubt there's anything that does EXACTLY what I want, but if there are good ways to bring a classes own interface to the forefront, or at least get NSObject out of the way, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: you mean to say you want to write your custom class method inspite of using cocoa class method right??

Comment: No, this is specifically about code completion.  I rather not have my code completion list to be littered with NSObject methods...  Would prefer for code completion to give some preference to methods of the class over inherited methods.  In other environments (C#, Java), this is less of an issue b/c the base object doesn't have a ton of methods, so an objects 'intended' interface jumps right out when using completion.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I agree... or even highlight them in bold like VS2012 (the far superior IDE) does

Comment: There isn't any (native) way to customize Xcode's code completion, unfortunately. It uses some secret heuristics to decide how to order results, but it supposedly does learn which results you use and orders them first.

Comment: Thumbs up for a very clear question. I'd suggest to raise a bug with Apple. It'd be a very cool addition to the _Xcode_.

Comment: I was just thinking today how much I hated that i get: index(<#const char *#>, <#int#>) when I am trying to get indexPath and wanting a way to give preferential treatment to code completion. Great Idea.

Comment: ... and why do I always get Nil, which I never use, when I type nil, which I use regularly? I really like the idea of being able to group by inheritance proximity.

Comment: This probably isn't what you want to hear, but AppCode. As a code editor it generally embarrasses the living daylights out of Xcode. To illustrate by addressing your question, completions from the current class appear first, then the superclass, and so on. And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @Adrian that is actually interesting to hear... what you've described is pretty much exactly what i want.  $100 for a single-platform IDE is a tough pill to swallow, but assuming there is a demo, maybe i'll check it out.

Comment: It's not just better code completion - there's a lot in there that takes away the drudgery (which I loathe) and lets you work faster, eg. code generation. Make sure you put the time in to explore during the demo period. Not cheap I know, but if you're coding professionally it pays for itself in saved time. And the removal of friction adds to your sanity - that's worth $100 to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but you should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292155/how-to-include-doxygen-method-description-in-xcodes-autocomplete-popup) for a cool way to show more info during autocompletion, at least.