# Is NS_ROOT_CLASS 'safe' for IOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have a situation where I have a purely static stateless facade for providing access to a collection of services.  I'm considering using NS_ROOT_CLASS as an alternative to providing a base class, since the facade has no memory management needs.  Consider:

```
NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface UtilityThing
+ (void) Service1;
+ (void) Service2;
@end
```

Service1 & Service2 effectively represent 'singleton-like' instances of service classes. So calling code looks like:

[[UtilityThing Service1] thingService1Does];

Aside from the fact that it has no instance data, I chose NS_ROOT_CLASS in part to simplify usage of the class, so that the only code-completion suggestions are the relevant ones (re: [XCode 5: Is there any way to group/filter/sort what shows up in code-completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428127/xcode-5-is-there-any-way-to-group-filter-sort-what-shows-up-in-code-completion))

Does anyone know if there are any gotchas to this pattern which might prevent an application from passing certification?  Or if there are other technical considerations that I should make when using NS_ROOT_CLASS?

Comment: How is this better than just defining global functions `UtilityService1` and `UtilityService2`?

Comment: Only slightly, perhaps, because user doesn't need to sort through all of Utility* to understand what services are available...  Although a verbose convention like UtilityService* could work, too.

Comment: @robmayoff - and in this case, i wanted the singleton instances of the services to know about each other, without the underlying services being implemented as singletons.  So the facade also injects necessary references into each service.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you *can* do that.

But don't.

Defining a new root class -- even a new root class containing nothing but class methods -- is an exceedingly atypical pattern.  I.e. pretty much never done.   Never done to the point that it is likely that the debugger and/or other dev tools may treat it slightly oddly.

Just declare it to be a subclass of `NSObject`.   Or create a singleton and make them instance methods because, almost assuredly, you'll end up wanting to store state as a part of your utilities and you'll have to refactor at that point.

Note:  Methods should start with lower case letters.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no overhead for making a class a subclass of NSObject — but there are a ton of gotchas involved in making your own root class.

Comment: I added a little more context for the use-case above.  While I still believe that your answer may make sense, I realized on reading it that I left out a couple of potentially important bits.

Comment: @J.Paulding The code completion reason is valid, but my experience is generally that class methods of this nature quickly get re-factored into instance methods for the stateful reasons I mentioned.  But, with that said, there really aren't any issues with creating a root class *as long as you don't try to instantiate said class*.   The entire stack of frameworks on the system expects everything to be a subclass of NSObject (or very carefully designed proxy).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is OK. You are allowed to create your own root class. It looks correct if you do not need to create instances of `UtilityThing`.