# Doxygen Documentation in Xcode 5 makefile project

Tags: c++, makefile, documentation, xcode5, doxygen

according to [this link](http://confusatory.org/post/63488534619/documentation-in-xcode-5) Xcode 5 should be able to interpret doxygen-like documentation, and make them show up in quick help. A similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292155/how-to-include-doxygen-method-description-in-xcodes-autocomplete-popup), however there was no info on what to do if it doesn't work.

I'm working on an external c++ makefile project, using Xcode only to make coding and debugging easier. The project is compiling and running correctly. I'm using a framework called COIN-BCP, which is fully doxygen documented. I can also create the doxygen html documentation from the terminal, it works fine. However, in the quick help in Xcode it doesn't show up [image: no quick help]

My questions are:

1. Do I have to turn on any extra settings in Xcode to make this work?
2. Does the makefile project have anything to do with the problem? I'm not exactly sure when Xcode is supposed to interpret the doxygen comments. During compilation?
3. Does anyone have a working makefile project, where the quick help documentation works?
4. Any suggestions how I could fix this? Also, I'd be happy to try any workarounds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re. 1: on by default. Re. 2: yes, in so far as it determines options sent to Clang. 
There are some compiler options, including a documentation warnings option here: [Clang Comment Parsing Options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#comment-parsing-options). As the Clang parsing is not as mature as doxygen, it's possible that its not as tolerant of formatting. Does it work with simplest format comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by following [this guide](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/07/xcode-4-code-completion-for-external-build-projects/).